# Storing Bing maps data in SQL Server, creating a route from saved location

Tags: sql-server, windows-phone-7, geolocation, windows-phone-7.1, bing-maps

I want to store locations in the form of longitude & latitude in SQL Server. I'd then want to retrieve and display it on Bing Maps. The goal would be to show route to them from the user's current location.

I think there is a location service which is different from Bing Maps, and maybe it would be provide me with what I need.

How can all of this be done?

Answer (score 1):

[Here is a pretty good article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh148148.aspx) that shows how you can visualize routes in a Windows Phone application. As of SQL CE storage, you might want to [start here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202860%28v=VS.92%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look on WP7 Code Samples:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431744(v=vs.92).aspx

Local Database Sample

Location Service Sample


Also try this: http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-Phone-7-Development-for-Absolute-Beginners/GPS-Location-API-and-Calling-Web-Services